# Calling a member pointer to a member method from outside the class C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I would like to call a function pointer pointing to a member function from outside said class (the function pointer is also a member of the same class).

Unfortunately the following produces an error:

> error: identifier "function_pointer" is undefined

```
#include <iostream>

class test_class {
public:
    void (test_class::*function_pointer)(int);
    void test_function(int input) {
        std::cerr << input << std::endl;
    }
    test_class() {
        function_pointer = &test_class::test_function;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    test_class foo;
    (foo.*function_pointer)(5);
    return 0;
}
```

I can call it from within the class, but I would like to avoid the unnecessary mess.

```
#include <iostream>

class test_class {
public:
    void (test_class::*function_pointer)(int);
    void test_function(int input) {
        std::cerr << input << std::endl;
    }
    test_class() {
        function_pointer = &test_class::test_function;
    }
    void call_from_within(int input) {
        (this->*function_pointer)(input);
    }
};

int main(void) {
    test_class foo;
    foo.call_from_within(5);
    return 0;
}
```

In short: What is the proper syntax to calling the `function_pointer` from outside the class?

Comment: If you want to avoid messes, then I suggest you look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: I assume this is a contrived example seeing as you would be much better just calling "test_function" instead of having any function pointers? Also might want to look into std::function

Comment: This is not working because `test_function` is not declared as `static`.

Comment: `(this->*function_pointer)(input);` is in fact `(this->*this->function_pointer)(input);`. So you can better imagine how to call it from outside of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(foo.*foo.function_pointer)(5);
```

accessing members (`function_pointer`) you need to specify which instance they belong to

as a more complicated example why this is required:

```
test_class foo, bar;
(foo.*bar.function_pointer)(5);
```

Comment: I guess I was working under the wrong assumption that the first foo was enough to specify which instance of the class the function should operate on.
So the first one is merely to access the method and the second one is used as the implicit parameter for the method (i.e. the instance to operate on)?

Answer (score 1):

Either use *Gruffalo*'s solution, or put that function pointer declaration **outsite the class**:

```
class test_class{
    ...
};
void (test_class::*function_pointer)(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers.

Since it is `c++` you can also use `std::function` for this. (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for further information)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class test_class{
public:
    std::function<void(int)> function_pointer;

    void test_function(int input)
    {
      std::cerr << input << std::endl;
    }

    test_class()
    {
      function_pointer = std::bind(&test_class::test_function, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
  test_class foo;

  foo.function_pointer(5);

  return 0;
}
```

Note: you have to use `std::bind` with `this` because it is a member function in your case.

Comment: Out of curiosity, assuming you called this particular function many times, which approach would perform faster, calling as `(foo.*foo.function_pointer)(5)` or using the std::function approach? If there is any difference at all.

Comment: or `function_pointer = [this](int i) { test_function(1); });` for the sake of readability

Comment: @Qubit: `std::function` uses a virtual call inside, so I'd expect calling a function pointer can be a tad faster, though the difference in negligible in most cases. From readability point of view, I'd prefer this approach to a function pointer